# SOQL Query to fetch more than 2000 records

Tags: salesforce, soql

How to fetch more than 2000 records through SOQL ....
Is there something query more ?

Comment: Is SOQL SalesForce.com Object Query Language?  If so, did you mean to tag this as Adobe Flex?

Comment: I retagged the question to SOQL

Answer (score 5):

call queryMore with the queryLocator provided in the first set of results, keep calling it with the next queryLocator until the done flag is true. See the [Web Services API](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Web_Services_API#API) docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this manually as well if you order by id and then query again with "where id > : idPrevious". If you try this just as I've typed it you'll hit a problem however, you can't use > and < with id fields. There is a simple work around for this though, just create a text type formula field which takes it's value from the id field. Then you can use that field in the query with no problems.

Of course if you're just looking to process loads of data then you might really be looking for Batch Apex.

Comment: but the id of sales force are not sequential i mean they are not integers !!

Comment: Correct, but if you sort by ID they'll always be in the same order, so  minor discrepancies could occur if data is updated while you're running through the set, but otherwise this works as you require.

Comment: where id> preivious id . ">" invalid operator on id . SO the above logic doesnt work

Comment: Did you use a formula field with the value of the ID instead of the ID field itself?